# D3 Maps of Specific states or countries or provinces

Tags: json, d3.js, geocoding, geojson

I am just learning how to use D3js and have come across some great examples of state maps or country maps with existing json files. I am wondering how I can find the json data for different state or countries.  For example, if I just wanted to show a simple map of France or a simple map of Montana, or just the province of Alberta (in Canada), where would I find the json data for this ?.

Comment: Geographic data can be found in many places, for countries and US states (not Canadian provinces), [this is a good source](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries). However, there are few comprehensive libraries of geojson for select locations. For most locations, searching for a shapefile of the location at hand is usually most fruitful, converting to geojson is easy with sites such as mapshaper.org.

Comment: In Australia, for instance, I get the shapefiles in the Australian Bureau of Statistics: http://www.abs.gov.au/ That being said, voting to close your question as off topic.